# Why is the autoplot function giving an error in this example from publication "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" not working?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, autoplot

I am working through section 2.2 "Time Plots" of publication *Forecasting: Principles and Practice* by Hyndman and Athanasopoulos (https://otexts.com/fpp3/time-plots.html) and I can't get the `autoplot()` function referenced therein to work. I assume `autoplot()` derives from the forecast package but as you can see in the below code I have also fiddled with ggplot2 and ggfortify packages and neither of these work either. The error I get when trying the forecast package is "***Error in `forecast::autoplot()`:! Objects of class <tbl_ts> are not supported by autoplot.***"

Any ideas how to get this `autoplot()` function working?

Here's the publication's `autoplot()` output that I'm trying to ape:

[image]

**Code** (in this example I was trying forecast package by using `forecast::autoplot(...)`; further note that installing the tsibbledata package provides the "ansett" data used in this example):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
library(tsibbledata)
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

melsyd_economy <- ansett %>%
  filter(Airports == "MEL-SYD", Class == "Economy") %>%
  mutate(Passengers = Passengers/1000)

forecast::autoplot(melsyd_economy, Passengers) +
  labs(title = "Ansett airlines economy class",
       subtitle = "Melbourne-Sydney",
       y = "Passengers ('000)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autoplot` method for `tsibble`s is from the `fabletools` package. See [Plot time series from a tsibble](https://fabletools.tidyverts.org/reference/autoplot.tbl_ts.html).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibbledata)
library(fabletools)

melsyd_economy <- ansett %>%
  filter(Airports == "MEL-SYD", Class == "Economy") %>%
  mutate(Passengers = Passengers / 1000)

autoplot(melsyd_economy, Passengers) +
  labs(
    title = "Ansett airlines economy class",
    subtitle = "Melbourne-Sydney",
    y = "Passengers ('000)"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: This also works for me using the feasts package

Comment: Yeah. Also when using `fable`. But the method is still from the `fabletools` package. But I have to admit that I have no clue why it works with feasts. Did not found anything in the package meta.

Comment: `autoplot()` is from the ggplot2 package, but is re-exported by forecast and fable. Both fable (`<fbl_ts>`), and forecast (`<forecast>`) classes should work with `autoplot()` if you use `ggplot2::autoplot()`, or just `autoplot()`. If this doesn't work, you might need to update your packages or there is a bug that can be reported in the GitHub issues.

Comment: @MitchellO'Hara-Wild The `autoplot` method from `ggplot2` does nothing as is evident from the source code (see https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/HEAD/R/autoplot.r). It simply "defines the S3 generic that other classes and packages can extend." That's what `fabletools` is doing. It defines an `autoplot` method for `tsibble`s, i.e. for objects of class `tbl_ts`. See https://github.com/tidyverts/fabletools/blob/master/R/plot.R.

Comment: Hi Mitchell, I completely reinstalled R and all packages (from CRAN) yesterday so I am now completely up-to-date with everything.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that ggplot2's `autoplot()` function just provides the generic, which is re-exported by the forecast and fabletools packages. I suggest using `ggplot2::autoplot()` incase there is an issue with the `forecast` or `fbl_ts` method registration.